# How do you load multiple arrays into a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am calling some JSON and loading a table with the data from a single array. That's working great. Now I'm trying to figure out

**A.** the best way to load the data into the table and

**B.** the best way to section that data off.

*This is my 6th week of iOS development and I am pretty new. I have a fairly weak Javascript background.*

My first (failed attempt) way to concatenate the arrays together and pass that to the tableview. I think this is wrong for multiple reasons (issues with sectioning afterwards, know "which" one to delete, etc). Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Didn't work:**

```
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:&errorJson];
self.allGroups = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"all_groups"];  //NSDictionary
  self.firstGroup = [self.allGroups objectForKey:@"first_group"]; //NSMutableArray
  self.secondGroup = [self.allGroups objectForKey:@"second_group"]; //NSMutableArray
  self.thirdGroup = [self.allGroups objectForKey:@"third_group"]; //NSMutableArray

NSMutableArray *allGroupsArray = [self.firstGroup arrayByAddingObjectsInArray:[self.secondGroup arrayByAddingObjectsInArray:self.thirdGroup]];
```

**Does work now, but can't figure out multiple arrays into the tableview:**

```
-(void) getTheData {

  NSString *sessionToken = [[AFOAuthCredential retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:@"myToken"] accessToken];

    if (sessionToken == nil) {
        LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:loginView animated:NO completion:nil];
        return;
    }

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://greatwebsitetogetdata.com"];
  AFOAuth2Client *oauthClient = [AFOAuth2Client clientWithBaseURL:url clientID:@"MY_CLIENT" secret:@"1234567890abc"];

  [oauthClient getPath:@"/api/v1/json" parameters:@{@"access_token": sessionToken} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      NSError *errorJson = nil;
  NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:&errorJson];
  self.allGroups = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"all_groups"];  //This is a NSDictionary
  self.firstGroup = [self.allGroups objectForKey:@"first_group"]; //This is a NSMutableArray
  self.secondGroup = [self.allGroups objectForKey:@"second_group"]; //This is a NSMutableArray
  self.thirdGroup = [self.allGroups objectForKey:@"third_group"]; //This is a NSMutableArray

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.firstGroup.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *groupInfo = self.firstGroup[indexPath.row];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    groupTableViewCell *cell = (groupTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[groupTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.groupTitle.text= groupInfo[@"title"];
    cell.groupLikes.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", groupInfo[@"likes"]];
    cell.groupRunDates.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", groupInfo[@"start_date"], groupInfo[@"end_date"]];
    cell.groupAcceptance.text= groupInfo[@"acceptance_type"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you modify the JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an array of arrays would work better for you, where each array represents a section. allGroups should then contain 3 arrays.
Then you need to override the datasource method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.allGroups.count;
}
```

and then in:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.allGroups[section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray *group = self.allGroups[indexPath.section];
    NSDictionary *groupInfo = group[indexPath.row];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    groupTableViewCell *cell = (groupTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[groupTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.groupTitle.text= groupInfo[@"title"];
    cell.groupLikes.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", groupInfo[@"likes"]];
    cell.groupRunDates.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", groupInfo[@"start_date"], groupInfo[@"end_date"]];
    cell.groupAcceptance.text= groupInfo[@"acceptance_type"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: self.allGroups is a NSDictionary so that block before the if statement inside the tableview code isn't working. My JSON has a group of groups if that makes sense.

Comment: As I wrote, i think you should make allGroups an array of arrays. Then it will work.

Comment: I mentioned I tried that and it didn't work. The code is above in the "Didn't work" section.

Comment: No, in your example you are putting all elements into a linear one-dimensional array. I propose using a two dimensional array: @[firstGroup, secondGroup, thirdGroup]